# OutputCache attribute on a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, outputcache

I have a ASP.NET MVC 4 controller that looks like this:

```
#if !DEBUG
    [OutputCache]
#endif
    public class LearningController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Articles(string name)
        {
            ... return dynamic content here based on name
        }
    }
```

Then I have a RouteConfig which maps "name" to the  URL, like this:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Articles",
            url: "learning/articles/{name}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Learning", action = "Articles" }
        );
```

The caching appears to work. When I set a `@DateTime.Now` in the .cshtml file and use release, it is indeed caching. Additionally, each article (by name) is returning the dynamic content correctly as well. What's more, is if I revert to query string (remove the MapRoute altogether), it *still* all works correctly.

Can anyone explain to me why this is working properly without a `VaryByParam`? I ask because I'm concerned that the dynamic action is not caching properly, or when I go into production might start serving incorrect content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{name}` parameter is part of the URI because you added it to your route, and OutputCache always caches each URI independently. 
`VaryByParam` would only affect the query string of `HttpGet` methods, e.g. `/learning/articles?name=abc` would cache `/learning/articles/` unless you defined `VaryByParam="name"` (or `*` instead of `name`).

Comment: I agree with the URI part, but as mentioned if you remove the routing (so it is using querystring) it still works properly. Accessing ?name=abc and ?name=xyc still yields different pages, despite the `OutputCache`. This is the part I do not understand.

Comment: MVC works with that route per default, doesn't matter if you call it {name} or {id}, if you url is /controller/action, it will always work like that